# General theory about OpenCV Descriptor Matching: What does every single step mean?

Tags: opencv

I'm quiet new to OpenCV and image processing, so my questions to the [feature matching approach](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html) a a bit general. I read something about the theory, but i have problems to arrange the very specific theory in this steps;

As i understand it i would group the sequence in the following steps:

- Feature detection: Special points from image are found in a very
- Feature description: Information about the near neighborhood is collected and a per featurepoint one vector is created 
   *->(1) is this always in the form of an histogram?*
- Matching: A distance between the descriptors is calculated
   *->(2) can I determine what kind of distance is used? I read about χ^2 and EMD, even if they are not implemented, are these the right keywords in this place*

  Corresponding matches are determined
   *->(3) I guess the Hungarian method would be one method?*
- Transformation estimation: In an optimization problem the best position is estimated

It would be nice if someone could clarify the italic marked question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your post  in its current form is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your right,  Micka confirmed my thoughts - so from my point of view the question may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(1): is this always in the form of an histogram?*

No, for example there are binary descriptors for ORB features. In Theory, descriptors can be anything. Often they are normalized and often they are either binary or floating points. But: Histograms have some properties which can make them good descriptors.

*(2) can I determine what kind of distance is used?*

For floating point descriptors, sum of squared distances might be the most used metric to measure the distance. For binary descriptor afaik, hamming distance is used?

*(3) I guess the Hungarian method would be one method?*

Could be used, I guess, but this might or might not lead to some problems. Typically nearest neighbor approaches are used. Often just brute-force (which is O(n^2) instead of O(n^3) of hungarian). The "problem", that multiple descriptors of one set might have the same nearest neighbor in the second set, is in fact another feature, because if that happens, you might be able to filter out some "uncertain" matches (often the ratio of the best n matches is used to filter out even more). You must assume that many descriptors in a set will have no fitting correspondence in the second set and you must assume, that the matching itself won't produce perfect matches. Typically some additional steps like homography computation are used to make the matching more robust and filter out outliers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Micka! Your answer enlightens my confusions a lot!